# C++ time_t problem

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, time

I'm having trouble with dates management in C++ (VS 2008).

According to [MSDN specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/323b6b3k%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), `time_t` represents:

*The number of seconds since January 1, 1970, 0:00 UTC*

therefore, I've written this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

time_t GetDate(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min, int sec)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    
    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = gmtime ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo->tm_year = year - 1900;
    timeinfo->tm_mon = month - 1;
    timeinfo->tm_mday = day;
    timeinfo->tm_hour = hour;
    timeinfo->tm_min = min;
    timeinfo->tm_sec = sec;
    timeinfo->tm_isdst = 0; // disable daylight saving time
    
    time_t ret = mktime ( timeinfo );
    
    return ret;
}

int main ()
{
    time_t time_0 = GetDate(1970,1,1,0,0,0);
    // time_0 == -1 !!!
    time_t time_1 = GetDate(1970,1,1,1,0,0);
    // time_1 == 0 !!!
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to be shifted by 1 hour (i.e. zero time is January 1, 1970, 1:00 UTC).

Initially, I thought the problem could come from the DayLightSaving flag, but it doesn't change by changing it.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks in advance

---

P.S.
In theory, I might not mind the zero time value, because it's only a reference time.

But I need to be sure about the value, because I'm porting the code to another language and I need to get exactly the same results.

---

### EDIT:

here's the solution, thanks to [Josh Kelley Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660983/c-time-t-problem/3661129#3661129)

```
time_t mktimeUTC(struct tm* timeinfo)
{
    // *** enter in UTC mode
    char* oldTZ = getenv("TZ");
    putenv("TZ=UTC");
    _tzset();
    // ***

    time_t ret = mktime ( timeinfo );

    // *** Restore previous TZ
    if(oldTZ == NULL)
    {
        putenv("TZ=");
    }
    else
    {
        char buff[255];
        sprintf(buff,"TZ=%s",oldTZ);
        putenv(buff);
    }
    _tzset();
    // ***

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: -1 is an error condition, not 1 second before Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: He should check errno on the -1 return and see what it is set to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mktime` takes a `struct tm` giving a **local** time and returns the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, 0:00 **UTC**.  Therefore, your `GetDate(1970,1,1,0,0,0);` call will return 0 if your local time zone is UTC but may return other values for other time zones.

**Edit:** For a UTC version of `mktime` or your `GetDate`, try the following (untested):

1. Call [`getenv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) to save the current value of the TZ environment variable (if any).
2. Call [`putenv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83zh4e6k%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) to change the TZ environment variable to "UTC".
3. Call [`_tzset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90s5c885%28VS.80%29.aspx) to make your changes active.
4. Call `mktime`.
5. Restore the old value of TZ, then call `_tzset` again.

Comment: Yes, I got it. And how can I get the UTC date corresponding to 1970,1,1,0,0,0 in my timezone ?

Comment: @digEmAll: You just did. UTC time is constant it does not matter what time zone you are in. Local time (what struct tm holds) is always relative to the current time zone. If you mean how do I get it to return zero. Work out what time it was in your local when it was 00:00:00 on Jan 1/1970 at the Meridian (I assume that is where UTC is time from).

Comment: @Martin: sorry, my previous comment was bad-written (I'm not english). I meant that if I could get (possibly with a function) the corresponding value of 1970/1/1 0:0:0 UTC in my timezone (i.e. 1970/1/1 1:0:0) mktime would return the correct value (i.e. 0)

Answer (score 1):

Just a WAG but try the following:

```
timeinfo->tm_year = year - (unsigned long)1900;
timeinfo->tm_mon = month - (unsigned long)1;
```

Comment: 1900 is correct see --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z9czt0w%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Ehm...what is TM environment var ?

Comment: yeah... josh explained it better than I did.

Comment: why to convert to `unsigned long` ??? if year is `unsigned` then 1900 will be converted to `unsigned`.  Why don't use `1900UL` then ? What's the reason of this answer? You are just adding noise to this thread.